# What are the differences between i18n and l10n in AngularJS 1.3, 1.4 and 2?

Tags: angularjs, localization, internationalization

I have an AngularJS application written using AngularJS 1.4. We need to adapt this to work with different languages and of course sometime in the future we need to move to AngularJS 2.0.

Has anyone out there used the i18n and l10n features of both AngularJS 1.4 and 2? From what I understand 1.4 adds new features over 1.3 but I cannot find any information on what has changed :-(

What I would like to know is if there are some big differences.  Big enough that we should wait until AngularJS 2.0 before starting internationalization.

Please do not close this question.  Yes I know it may not fit exactly as a perfect question but I am pretty sure there are developers out there who are asking the same question as me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since AngularJS 2.0 will be a whole rewrite I don't think it is a good idea to rely on being able to migrate from previous versions. Moreover, it is not going to be released soon and even version 1.4 is not stable yet.

You should be always using the latest stable version. However, there is an [official thread about migrating](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/docs/guide/migration).

If you want to learn about specific changes e.g. [l10n and i18n](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/docs/guide/i18n) have a look at the [changelog](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md).

Comment: Thanks. I seem to recall one of the improvements in 1.4 was localisation. But can't see what they actually changed.